# I checked Publishing features at both Site and subsite level

Tags: publishing, template, features

I checked Publishing features at both site collection and sub-site level. But it shows SharePoint Server Publishing already disabled since the button says "Activate".

I am trying to save a sub-site as a template to be able to create new sub-sites with the same structure. I'm at loss of what to do.

Answer (score 1):

**HOW TO SAVE SITE AS A TEMPLATE**

As mention above by @yash.kamdar the "**Save site as a template**" feature is disabled by default, to save your site as template you have to enable this feature, To enable this service  follow this steps:

**1.)** Select site you wanted to save as template.

example: (https://ahlcloud.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectSite)

**2.)** Open your **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** then (**run as administor**).

**3.)** Type this syntax on your **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** just like on the image below.

**Powershell Script:**

```
    $AdminCenterURL = "https://MyTenantDomain-admin.sharepoint.com" 
    $SiteURL = "https://MyTenantDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/myTemplate"
    Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminCenterURL -credential (Get-Credential)
    Set-SPOSite $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

**Example:**
[image]
While entering this code

`Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminCenterURL -credential (Get-Credential)`

Windows Security Credential will prompt then enter your **[sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint)** account .

[image]

Then enter the last syntax to enable "**Save site as a template**" feature.

```
Set-SPOSite $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

**4.)** Enter this link on your browser :
http://MyTenantdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/MySiteTemplate/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

Example : `https://ahlcloud.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectSite/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx`

***Note:** If you don't follow step #3 you will receive this error when saving template using the short-link above.*
[image]

TAGS: [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint)[commandpromt](/questions/tagged/commandpromt)[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)[features](/questions/tagged/features)[template](/questions/tagged/template)[publishing](/questions/tagged/publishing)

Answer (score 0):

Save site as a template is disabled by default in Publishing sites and Collaboration sites with the publishing features active.

Follow the steps below-

1. Open the site with SharePoint designer
2. In the ribbon go to Site Options
3. Locate the options SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled and modify the value to true.

[image]

Since the site template is disabled in the Publishing sites the option Save Site as Template is not available in the Site Settings you will need to navigate to the page directly: http://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

Provide all the details and click OK after a couple of minutes you will have the WSP site template generated.